# Dialog error when open from a Adapter + ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, dialog, adapter

I have a little problem with a Dialog.
It's a ListView of Videos with thumbnails that load the videos with an Adapter. The ListView register an OnItemClickListener and inside the OnClickItem method I try to raise the Dialog.

I've tried with various types of Dialog but nothing happened. A simplified piece of code it's here:

```
public class ListOfVideos extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.list_of_videos);
          init_phone_video_grid();
    }

    private void init_phone_video_grid() {

        // Here's some code for the video reading

        // The ListView
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Here's some code for the video reading

                /** ============= Here's the problem ================ **/
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Example Message")
                        .setTitle("This is the title!!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNeutralButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

                System.out.println("[debug]" + "Open File " + filename);
            }
        });
    }
```

The list of videos load perfectly. But when I click on an Item:

1. The Dialog does not show
2. I got a error message in the LogCat, that state:  "show() Dialog's window is null!"
3. The println debug message, appears ok in the LogCat

I have searched for that message error, but there's not much information.

I think the problem could be on the Context that receive the Builder, but I'm stuck on this point.

Any advice will be apreciated

Comment: Try getting the Context for the AlertDialog.Builder from the Activity instead of the View passed. I.e., ListOfVideos.this instead of v.getContext().

Comment: Hell yeah!!!! that was the trick... If you post it as an Answer, I'll accept it... :)
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is saying that the `Context` given to the `AlertDialog.Builder` has no attached window, which `Dialog`s need as a UI anchor, basically. An `Activity` is what should be used for such a `Context`, as it will have the required window.

Without seeing `VideoAdapter`'s code, the root cause is presumably `new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext())`, which is handing your `VideoAdapter` the application `Context` to build `View`s with. That likely means that the `v` passed into `onItemClick()` is one such `View`, and `v.getContext()` is returning that application `Context` in `new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())`.

That application `Context` does not have a window but your `Activity` does, as mentioned. Furthermore, the `Activity` is actually what you want to give to `VideoAdapter` to build `View`s with anyway, to ensure that they are created with the correct theme and styling. Change that relevant line to:

```
videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(ListOfVideos.this));
```

That alone might solve the issue, depending on what `VideoAdapter` does internally. However, it's arguably better to specify the `Activity` again in the `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor call, just so there's no question:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListOfVideos.this);
```

As a final note, whenever a `Context` is needed for any UI component, you usually want to use the immediately available `Activity`.

Comment: That solved the problem. I'm not really sure to understand the difference, but it works. I'll investigate a little more.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example of How to create dialog box..

```
        String message = "Hello";
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                CurrentActi.this);
        alt_bld.setTitle("Alert")
        .setMessage(message)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                //here right the code that you want perform onClick

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.setTitle("Alert");
        alert.show();
```

May be it will help you..